# Is there a way to make sound play through different screens in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Is there a way to make sound play through different screens? Right now, the sound stops playing for me once you go to a different screen. I want the sound to continue playing, even when screens are changing and it goes to a different screen.Here's the code I used for this:
.py code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file("test1.kv")

class a62(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.play_sound, 1)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.next_screen4, 1.5) #music.mp3 needs to continue playing even when it reaches a17 and 18
        Clock.schedule_once(self.next_screen5, 2.5)

    def play_sound(self, dt):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('sound/music.mp3')  
        if sound:
            print("playing sound123")
            sound.volume = 1
            sound.play()

    def next_screen4(self, dt):
        self.manager.current = "a17"

    def next_screen5(self, dt):
        self.manager.current = "a18"


class a17(Screen):
    pass


class a18(Screen):
    pass


class CandDApp(App):

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(a62(name="a62"))
        sm.add_widget(a17(name="a17"))
        sm.add_widget(a18(name="a18"))
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CandDApp().run()
```

.kv code:

```
<a62>:
    Button:
        text: "a62"
<a17>:
    Button:
        text: "a17"
<a18>:
    Button:
        text: "a18"
```

Comment: I run your code using Python v3.10.4, kivy v2.1.0, and ffpyplayer 4.3.5 under Ubuntu 22.04. It works as expected with the Screen changes having no effect on the sound. What versions are you running?

Comment: maybe you should create player outside screens - ie inside `CandDApp`

Comment: I tried putting it in CanDApp already, that doesn't fix it.
I'm not sure what versions I'm running, but it should all be the most recent version. I tried running the code for me, but for some reason it only works sometimes. Half of the times the sound cuts out, but half of the time it works. I assume it's something on kivy's side with memory or something, but I just gave up on sound for now because I don't know how to fix this at all.